# Excel distorting markers in scatter plot

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I've run into an issue with scatter plots in Excel. For whatever reason, Excel is distorting the appearance of markers on the plot, such that markers within the same series do not look the same. For example, in a series with circular markers, some of the markers appear as ellipses, some appear as smaller circles, etc.

[image]

Does anyone know why Excel is doing this? Better yet, any ideas how to stop this? For reference, I'm copying these graphs into Adobe Illustrator to create graphics for a print application.

Comment: It may have to do with how the image gets rescaled.  Are you changing the size of the resulting image at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess: Try saving as (exporting to) to a PDF or other print format then copy the image from that.

Comment: Interestingly, the markers come out uniform in the PDF. However, the export reversed the direction of arrows on the axes (not shown above, sorry).  Nonetheless, this actually made the graph easier to manipulate in Illustrator, and the arrow issue was easily fixed. Thanks! +1

Comment: I should also mention that it works much better to just open the PDF in Illustrator rather than copying the chart image from Acrobat over to Illustrator.